# WP7 Development App/Page wide variable

Tags: windows-phone-7, global-variables

Does anyone know how to set a variable that can be accessed on all pages of a Windows Phone 7 App?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Without knowing any more specifics of your situation, you could create the variables as members of your App class:

```
  public partial class App : Application
  {
    ...
    public int foo { get; set; }
    ...
  }
```

Then access if from wherever:

```
  (App.Current as App).foo = 3;
```

Comment: Yes, you can generally replace "int" with whatever data type you wish.  Make sure you always access it from the same thread, or you will have to add your own synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

Setup global variables, quick and easy, make a new class for GlobalVariables:

```
public static class GlobalVariables
{
   public static string my_string = "";
   public static int my_int = -1;
}
```

Then you access the Global Variables class like this:

```
GlobalVariables.variable_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with some variables, I solved it initializing the variables in the constructor of the page and not in any method:

```
    Dictionary<string, int> clients;//Global variable

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        clients = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }
```