# Navigate to a web page from different page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

My app is a windows phone 7 application. In that i have created a UrlTextBox in MainPage.xaml and created a web browser control(browsers) in another page(Browser.xaml). If the user types some URL in the textbox and clicked on Go Button, i need to navigate from MainPage.xaml to Browser.xaml and even the web page should also load in Browser.xaml(i.e, whatever the URL typed by the user) in a single button click(GoBtn_Click). I used the Navigation service for the above, but it throws an error that "browsers" does not exist in the current context.
Need help for this. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding the question, but I think you're confusing NavigationService.Navigate and WebBrowser.Navigate. You can't do everything you said you wanted to do with just the navigation service.

First, store the URL. Then use this code to navigate to the Browser page:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Browser.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Then, once on the browser page, tell the WebBrowser to navigate to the supplied URL.

```
myBrowser.Navigate(myUrl);
```

Comment: How to store the URL and where?

Comment: There are plenty of ways you can do that. Probably the quickest way would be to add a property to your App class and then read/write to that by referencing Application.Current. Just handle it however else you're doing variables that are useful application-wide such as user preferences.

Comment: Do you have any sample project for this?

Comment: Try checking out the accepted answer for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405621/wp7-development-app-page-wide-variable

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand that. How will you do that for URL?

Comment: @RaghavMac: Try following link on Channel9 : Navigating and Passing Data between XAML Pages - Day 3 - Part 3 (http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Navigating-and-Passing-Data-between-XAML-Pages)