# Passing variable between XAML pages

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have two page : Start.xaml.cs and Settings.xaml.cs.
In Setting.xaml.cs i  get the data form accelerometer just one time and fix a initial posiotion. In Start.xaml.cs i read the data from accelerometer continously. I want to get the accelerometer data variables from Settings.xaml.cs and bring them to Start.xaml.cs to compare them. Could you help me to make it or give me some source of information of how could i do this?

Code for **Start.xaml.cs**

```
Accelerometer acc = new Accelerometer();

public Start()
{

    InitializeComponent();
    acc.ReadingChanged += new EventHandler<AccelerometerReadingEventArgs>(acc_ReadingChanged);
    acc.Start();
}

void acc_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
{
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => ThreadSafeAccelerometerChanged(e));
}

void ThreadSafeAccelerometerChanged(AccelerometerReadingEventArgs e)
{
    xText.Text = e.X.ToString("0.0000");
    yText.Text = e.Y.ToString("0.0000");
    zText.Text = e.Z.ToString("0.0000");
}
```

And here is the code for **Settings.xaml.cs**

```
Accelerometer acc = new Accelerometer();

private void Calib_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    acc.Start();
    acc.ReadingChanged += myAccelerometer_ReadingChanged;
}

void myAccelerometer_ReadingChanged(object sender, AccelerometerReadingEventArgs f)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
    {
        xBlock.Text = "X:"+f.X.ToString("0.0000");
        yBlock.Text = "Y:"+f.Y.ToString("0.0000");
        zBlock.Text = "Z:"+f.Z.ToString("0.0000");
        acc.Stop();
    });
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also send your accelerometer data to different page using NavigationService. This can be used to send simple data between pages.

```
// In your settings page use the following code
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.format("/Start.xaml?xValue={0}&yValue={1}&zValue={2}", xBlock.Text, yBlock.Text, zBlock.Text), UriKind.Relative));
```

And then in your Start.xaml.cs add the following code to the OnNavigatedTo method to read the data

```
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string x = "";
        string y = "";
        string z = "";

        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("xValue", out x);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("yValue", out y);
        NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("zValue", out z);
       // Then what ever you want to do with x,y and z value
    }
```

More on passing data between pages:- [Passing parameters between pages, Windows phone 8](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives)

Comment: It works but i want to keep the accelerometer data to settings.xaml.cs and don't navigate directly to start.xaml.cs. I want to go to a intermediary page like MainPage.xaml.cs and then go to Start.xaml.cs.

Comment: I think of something like transfer the data to MainPage.xaml.cs and from there to Start.xaml.cs or it exist a simplier method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The settings page should set members of a "global" class that both the main and settings page can access. Information on how to do that can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405621/wp7-development-app-page-wide-variable).

Ideally this class would just hold accelerometer type information.